# Changing the HTML file for Apache

Tags: command-line, apache2, html

I recently bought a domain and put an HTML and a CSS file for Apache with Ubuntu.

Anyway, now I want to change them. I removed the CSS file with `cd /var/www/HTML` and writing `sudo rm blabla.css`.

But I am not sure about running `rm index.html` since I am not sure what will be the effects. Also for some reason, I got some problems when I tried to move my other CSS and HTML files.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What 'problems' did you run into when trying to remove the CSS and HTML?

Answer (score 1):

There will be no issues with removing the HTML file.

Of course, if you visit the website nothing will be there - but you can make a new HTML file.

Rather than removing it, why not modify it? Use the following command:

```
sudo nano /var/www/html/index.html
```

and then you can change the contents.

To copy a file from one computer to another via PuTTY use this command:

```
pscp index.html user@remote-machine:/var/www/html/index.html
```

Comment: I connected to ubuntu with putty so I dont have gedit.I do have gedit in my virtual machine but I cannot copy something to the terminal and I want to change the whole file which would take me long.I appreciate your answer but can you tell me how can I upload the new html  and css file?I think it should be with mv and giving and adress but for some reason I couldnt make it work

Comment: @Curriculaa Telling us you were connecting with putty would have been helpfull...

Comment: @Curriculaa I've edited to explain how to do that

Comment: What does the first index.html refer to?Is it the adress of my own html file

Comment: @Curriculaa So you open a command prompt? You navigate to the folder with you `index.html` file in it. You run that command